# Jquery knowing which class triggered the event?

Tags: jquery

If I have this jquery...

```
$('.myClass, .myClass2').mouseover(function() {
     $(this).fadeIn('1000');
});
```

Is there a way to know if it came from `.myClass` or `.myClass2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check classes that exist on `$(this)` by using `.hasClass(className)`:

```
var item = $(this);
if (item.hasClass('myClass')) {
    // myClass triggered    
}
else if (item.hasClass('myClass2')) {
    // myClass2 triggered
}
```

Comment: @cgwebprojects May not be an issue depending on your situation, but you may want to use two separate `if` statements (rather than an `if else`) to handle the case where the element has both classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myClass, .myClass2').mouseover(function() {
     alert(this.className) 
     $(this).fadeIn('1000');
});
```

..

```
$('.myClass, .myClass2').mouseover(function() {
     if ( $(this).hasClass("myClass") ) {
         // do stuff for .myClass
     } 
     $(this).fadeIn('1000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$(this).hasClass('myClass');
```

Or get the name of the using

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely this would work:

```
var caller_class = $(this).attr('class');
```

or the vanilla JavaScript method of `this.className`;

Comment: No not really in my case as my html object may have many classnames and not always in the same order!

Comment: In that case, you're stuck with the `if($(this).hasClass('myClass'))` solution then.